# Problems figuring out what type of join to use in SQL

Tags: sql, join

Normally i use Linq to SQL to handle all database transaktions. But on the project i am currently working on i may only use pure SQL. The join i wish to do in SQL looks like this when i use Linq.

```
var query = (from districts in _db.SalesMenOnDistrict
                     join salesman in _db.Districts on districts.salesmanId equals salesman.SSN                      
                     where districts.districtId == district                      
                     select salesman);                   
        return query.ToList();
```

I my database i have three tabels. The first tabel is called SalesMen, this contains different salesmen. Table two contains different districts. The third tabel contains a SSN number from the salesmen tabel and a id from the district tabel. I wish to get all of the salesmen on the district id by using a join. I just dont know the syntax in SQL script. 
Here is what i got so far.

```
SELECT SSN, name
FROM SalesMan
INNER JOIN SalesMenOnDistrict
ON SalesMan.SSN = SalesMenOnDistrict.salesMan
```

when i do this i just get all of the salesmen returned and not just the ones on the specific district.

Comment: You have no WHERE clause to limit your results to the district you want

Comment: You have not implemented the WHERE clause part of the statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add a Where clause:

```
SELECT SSN, name
FROM SalesMan
INNER JOIN SalesMenOnDistrict
ON SalesMan.SSN = SalesMenOnDistrict.salesMan
WHERE SalesMenOnDistrict = @yourDesiredDistrict
```